# creating an array of affected rows and processing them each in another query

Tags: php, mysql

Overview:

I can't figure out how to create an array of affected rows from a query and process each of them in another query.

Details:

My first query marks any account that hasn't been signed into in the past 90 days inactive. In the table phpbb_users there's a column **user_id**. For any affected rows by this first query I would like I would like an array containing the **user_id**'s.

```
// first query

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_type = '1', user_inactive_time = '$inactivetime', theinactivereason = '90dayssincelastlogin', user_inactive_reason = '3' WHERE DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(user_lastvisit), INTERVAL 90 DAY) < NOW() AND user_type = '0' AND user_lastvisit != '0'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

I would then like to process each **userid** in the array from the first query through the second query and SET activenumber = '0' in the table phpbb_phonelist.

```
// second query -> $user_id is the column user_id corresponding to each row in the first query

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_phonelist SET activenumber = '0' WHERE whoid = '$user_id'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Try `left join` on update query with single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be inefficient to loop through all the users, so I will show you the recommended way.

You can have a **single** SQL statement like this (Please test on a DB copy first):

```
$result = 
mysql_query("UPDATE phpbb_users, phpbb_phonelist
    SET 
       phpbb_users.user_type = '1',
       phpbb_users.user_inactive_time = '$inactivetime', 
       phpbb_users.theinactivereason = '90dayssincelastlogin', 
       phpbb_users.user_inactive_reason = '3',
       phpbb_phonelist.activenumber = '0' 
    WHERE 
          DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(phpbb_users.user_lastvisit), INTERVAL 90 DAY) < NOW() 
       AND phpbb_users.user_type = '0' 
       AND phpbb_users.user_lastvisit != '0'
       AND phpbb_phonelist.whoid = phpbb_users.user_id ");
```

Not sure what your users ID column is.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll give this query you provided a try and hopefully I can understand it and resolve this issue in the future on my own. users_id is the same as the whoid column, I should of assigned them the same name in both tables.

Comment: It comes with practice. You'll get there. We all started there. Please do mark as answer when you confirm it works